# Why curly brackets are treated incorrectly when "commandchars" is used in "Verbatim"?

Tags: fancyvrb

This is what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=+\{\}]
Hello, \emph{world}!
Bye, +emph{world}!
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

The first line is rendered as `Hello, \emphworld!`, which is not correct. For some reason the `Verbatim` environment treats `{` and `}` as special chars, not as plain verbatim text. Without the `commandchars`, the first line renders correctly.

Comment: You're specifying three characters -- `+`, `{`, and `}` -- in the commandchars list. Notably, you're *not* specifying the backslash character itself as a commandchar. Hence, why would you expect `\emph{world}` to "work"? Do check out what happens if you specify `[commandchars=\\\{\}]`.

Comment: @Mico I expect `\emph{world}` to be treated verbatim, since it doesn't start with `+` and thus is not a "command"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `commandchars=+\{\}`, inside the environment `Verbatim`

- the character `+` has category code 0(escape) and thus during tokenization is treated in the way in which under normal circumstances/outside the environment `Verbatim` the backslash, `\` is treated.
- the character `{` has category code 1(begin group) and thus during tokenization is treated in the way in which it is treated under normal circumstances/outside the environment `Verbatim`.
- the character `}` has category code 2(end group) and thus during tokenization is treated in the way in which it is treated under normal circumstances/outside the environment `Verbatim`.

Any other character which usually has a special function in TeX, e.g., the backslash character, is tokenized under verbatim category code régime where these special characters are assigned

- either category code 12(other) so that they don't have special function any more but during typesetting are taken for directives for typesetting some glyph of a font
- or category code 13 (active) so that they can be defined to expand to some commands which in turn yield the typesetting of some symbols like `␣` for the space character or yield doing a line break for the carriage return character.

Tokenizing characters `{` of category 1 while not creating a control symbol token yields explicit character tokens of category 1(begin group).
Tokenizing characters `}` of category 2 while not creating a control symbol token yields explicit character tokens of category 2(end group).

Unlike explicit character tokens of category 11(letter) and 12(other) such explicit character tokens during typesetting are not directives for typesetting some glyph of a font, but are directives which affect grouping - either delimiting scopes or delimiting sets of tokens which are to form arguments.

Inside your `Verbatim`-environment, where `commandchars=+\{\}` is in effect, the line
`Hello, \emph{world}!`
is tokenized as
<kbd>H<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>e<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>l<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>l<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>o<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>,<sub>13</sub></kbd><kbd>*space*<sub>13</sub></kbd><kbd>\<sub>12</sub></kbd><kbd>e<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>m<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>p<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>h<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>{<sub>1</sub></kbd><kbd>w<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>o<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>r<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>l<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>d<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>}<sub>2</sub></kbd><kbd>!<sub>12</sub></kbd><kbd>*carriage return*<sub>13</sub></kbd>.

<kbd>\<sub>12</sub></kbd> comes into being because `\` of category code 12(other) does not cause LaTeX to start creating a control sequence token.

<kbd>{<sub>1</sub></kbd> and <kbd>}<sub>2</sub></kbd> affect scoping but do not yield s.th. visible in the .pdf-file.

Inside your `Verbatim`-environment, where `commandchars=+\{\}` is in effect, the line
`Bye, +emph{world}!`
is tokenized as
<kbd>B<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>y<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>e<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>,<sub>13</sub></kbd><kbd>*space*<sub>13</sub></kbd><kbd>\emph</kbd><kbd>{<sub>1</sub></kbd><kbd>w<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>o<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>r<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>l<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>d<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>}<sub>2</sub></kbd><kbd>!<sub>12</sub></kbd><kbd>*carriage return*<sub>13</sub></kbd>.

With `commandchars=+\{\}` in effect you can do `+string+{` / `+string+}` for typesetting curly braces. (You can also do `+string{` / `+string}` as long as `{` and `}` are balanced.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an excerpt from page 16 of the user guide of the [fancyvrb](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package:

[image]

Since you've specified

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=+\{\}]
```

the `+` character acts like `\` would in a normal setting, while `{` and `}` act as openers and closers of a TeX group. In consequence, `+emph{world}` renders "world" in italics inside the `Verbatim` environment.

In constrast, `\emph{world}` inside the `Verbatim` environment generates `\emphworld`, with all glyphs rendered in the upright monospaced font face. After all, because you've specified `{` and `}` to act as the openers and closers of a TeX group, they have a special meaning and do *not* get printed out.

Comment: I take it, it's impossible to do what I'm trying do: use curly brackets as command chars (after the slash) and at the same time as plain text verbatim symbols?

Comment: @UlrichDiez by the way, I'm getting `Runaway argument?` when I try to use `+string{` alone, without the closing `+string}`

Comment: @yegor256 you can use `+{` which is `\{` so typesets as `{`

Comment: @yegor256 You are right. I should have mentioned this. Whenever TeX reads a line of input from the .tex-file and creates tokens, this line is pre-processed: The encoding of the line is converted from the computer platform's encoding scheme so that characters are encoded in TeX's internal character encoding scheme which either is ASCII or is unicode. Then space characters at the right end of the line are removed. Then a character is appended whose number in TeX's internal character encoding scheme equals the value of the parameter `\endlinechar`. Then, as soon as TeX needs to create more  ...

Comment: @yegor256 ...Then, as soon as TeX needs to create more tokens, TeX looks at the characters which come from pre-processing the line of .tex-input and by and by creates tokens. ... Within the environment `Verbatim` a) the value of the integer parameter `\endlinechar` is 13 and thus in TeX's internal character encoding scheme, which either is ASCII or is unicode, denotes the carriage return character and b) the carriage return character is given the category 13(active) so that with tokens coming from tokenizing the characters of a line of .tex-input the end of the line is denoted by an ...

Comment: @yegor256... the end of the line is denoted by an explicit character token of character code 13 (carriage return) and category 13(active) and c) the input is iteratively processed linewise whereby an iteration of processing a line of input is initiated  by means of a macro which processes an argument. I overlooked that, of course, with macro arguments curly braces/explicit character tokens of category 1 (begin group) and explicit character tokens of category 2 (end group) need to be balanced as otherwise you might get ...

Comment: @yegor256 ... as otherwise you might get `! Argument of \FancyVerbGetLine has an extra }.` or  `Runaway argument` or whatever can happen in case the matching `}` of category 2(end group) of `{` of category 1(begin group) is missing. In this case the argument in question is delimited by an active carriage return/by an explicit character token of character code 13(carriage return) of category 13(active) so that as argument tokens are gathered that come from tokenizing a line of .tex-input.